# Were romantic feelings between Sam Carter and Jack O'Neill in Stargate SG-1 ever confirmed?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

It was often hinted that they both had romantic feelings for each other, but was it ever confirmed if they actually got together?

Comment: I seem to remember reading about an interview saying they basically "got busy" after the season 8 finale, but now I'm struggling to find it

Comment: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/stargate/images/c/c5/Stargate_Window_of_Opportunity_kiss.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111025195606

Comment: That picture is from the episode where Jack and Teal'c had their Groundhog Day.

Comment: I don't have the DVD handy, but I seem to recall that at the end of Continuum, the last scene is where they are all up at Jack's cabin by the lake, and Jack has his arm around Sam or they're holding hands or something like that.

Comment: @BBlake I know. That's why I didn't put it as an answer. It was just a funny scene.

Answer (score 16):

**No, it hasn't been confirmed (officially)** and with the [cancellation of the SGA film](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/ustv/news/a295235/sga-mallozzi-film-shelved-indefinitely.html#~pgh2YU25AWjVLE) **nor is it likely that it ever will be**.

That being said, all of the cast and crew interview are operating on the principle that they *did* end up having a sexual relationship. SG1's Producer (Joseph Malozzi) had this to offer [on his blog in 2008](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/december-8-2008-ships-and-what-ifs/);

> “But what about SG-1?” some of you will (and have) asked. Why didn’t
>   you ever confirm the Sam/Jack relationship in SG-1 but found the need
>   to confirm the McKay/Keller relationship in Atlantis? Well, two
>   reasons. 1) The Sam/Jack relationship was fraught with complications
>   given that he was her commanding officer. Pursuing any sort of
>   relationship would have been inappropriate for both and would only
>   have really been possible late in the series after Jack’s retirement.
>   Which brings us to – 2) Jack and Sam could have gotten together after
>   Jack’s retirement, but it was never made canon because, quite frankly,
>   it wasn’t my call. Still, despite the lack of official confirmation,
>   it was only natural that they should get together after the events of
>   Threads and, in my mind, they have been together ever since. An
>   attempt to suggest as much in season 4’s Trio unfortunately ended up
>   on the cutting room floor when the episode ran long.

And Amanda Tapping (the actress who plays Samantha Carter) had [this](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/march-30-2009-amanda-tapping-answers-your-questions/) to say;

> **Q. *What’s your take on Sam’s and Jack’s relationship? Dating, Engaged, Married?***
>
> **AT:** *Sleeping together…once he’s retired. Crazy, mad, passionate love. Way too much sexual tension for it not to pay off. Then, they’ll
>   take it from there. Dating….Fishing….Dating…..*
>
> **Q. *Do you want to see an acknowledgement of their relationship in the next movie? If so, will there be one?***
>
> **AT:** *I’d like to see some pay off for all their years together. But, I don’t have any say in that.*

Comment: I always have taken when two of the main characters start having romantic relationships in a series which didn't start out that way as *Jumping the Shark*. It usually shows the end of the show. Two main exceptions as of late are Bones and Castle. I think that was their plan all along with those, though.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Most writers never have any idea how to actually write a relationship, let alone how one develops.  The build-up and tease is easier.  Castle's been good, when they don't try to pump up drama.

Comment: @radhil - Sexual tension is a lot easier to write. You have them clearly indicate that they want to have sex, then come up with a reason why they can't. Then repeat.

Comment: @Richard - Plus all the witty one-liners. *"It's my sidearm, I swear..."*

Comment: Castle has really fallen off this last season. It started off strong, but the second half of the season really sucked.

Comment: @Paulster2 - yea, I'm pretty sure that Bones at least was intended that way all along. It was kind of a natural progression for the characters, especially Bones, since Booth was the first man who "got" her and stuck around despite her quirkiness.

Comment: @Richard: Huh. They didn't exactly have to come up with an original or even evolving reason why Carter and O'Neill can't have sex for this one.

Answer (score 5):

It was more than hinted at. In the Groundhog Day episode, Jack hands in his resignation one day and immediately and passionately kisses Sam. In another (the name of which eludes me), Jack and Sam are both questioned about the events of a certain mission, and both are found to be lying about those events. In the end, it turns out that Jack wouldn't leave Carter behind to die (or to somehow later escape on her own) because "he cared for her far more than is appropriate [for his position]", and he lied for that reason.

These are both explicit demonstrations of their love for each other, but as you say, they never actually get together because they *can't*. O'Neill would lose his career, which is extremely important to him, especially with respect to the work he does in the Stargate program.

Comment: As @CalCrypto noted in his [comment above](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93289/were-romantic-feelings-between-sam-carter-and-jack-oneill-in-stargate-sg-1-ever/95080#comment210477_93289), the scene where Jack kisses Sam is part of a "groundhog day" style episode and not part of the main continuity.

Comment: @Richard:   Why the downvote?  The kiss in the groundhog day episode does demonstrate their love/tension even if they couldn't act on it in the main timeline.   That is all Ernie is saying.   This is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - The essence of that episode is that in a consequence-free environment, both Teal'c and O'Neill are able to indulge themselves. That's hardly indicative of their normal feelings.

Comment: @Richard:  Not true at all.  You are taking what was a comical acknowledgment of the sexual tension in the main timeline and basically relegating it to "O'Neill is being a rapist".   Ernie uses that example and the other to prove his thesis that they ARE demonstrates, in-universe, to be attracted to each other, and he explains this in the next paragraph.   Seriously, quit it with the downvotes because it's someone else's answer, because this is how it reads whether you mean it or not.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - Ignoring the fact that I may downvote whatever I want (for whatever reason I choose) I simply don't believe that this episode accurately reflects their feelings. Note that he's acting completely out of character and her extreme surprise.

Comment: @Richard:  I'm not questioning your right.  I'm appealing to your sense of responsibility.  ----   In this case, Ernie explains that her surprise is because they can't act on their feelings.   She's doesn't know it's Groundhog Day, so she's surprised.   It's not a big leap.

Comment: There were also alternative timelines where O'Neill and Carter were married, primarily because Carter was a civilian in them. This happened several times in the series.

Comment: @Ernie - Indeed. That said, there were also alternate universes where they were dead, evil or just dead evil.

Comment: I don't think there was anyone in the command center that *wasn't* utterly shocked when O'Neill handed in his resignation in Groundhog Day. But it's still confirmation of Jack's feelings for Carter, don't you think?

Comment: Fun Fact: The "Groundhog Day" episode is in fact called "Window of Opportunity".

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit research and two producers said that in the third movie, [Stargate: Revolution](http://www.gateworld.net/movies/04.shtml) (that sadly never has been made) would have shown that they are in fact together.

> **Q.** “Emboldened by your last mailbag, I have one question to ask…and after all these years, I promise it will be my last S/J question ever…had we gotten the 3rd SG-1 movie, would the status of Sam and Jack’s post-Threads relationship have been made clear?”
>
> **A. [[Joseph Mallozzi]](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/march-1-2012-some-prelim-work-on-the-trailer-pics-from-the-stargate-vault-dark-matter-3-preview-mailbag/)**: All I can say to that is that, there’s a dinner scene in the first draft of Stargate: Revolution that made it pretty clear that Jack and Sam were, in fact, together.

---

Brad Wright also confirmed (in [this interview](https://youtu.be/p-Ubm0LqyAQ?t=1m21s)) that in the movie script he was writing there would be scene that would be ...

> "...shall we say, romantic?"

between them.

---

In the commentary to the Atlantis epiode "Trio" Ms Gero said that Sam and Jack are in a secret relationship. True it was deleted, but it has to mean something:

And then in the [Stargate Atlantis legacy](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis:_Legacy) series of books (approved by MGM) that clearly hint that they are secretly in a relationship and the newest book, coming this summer, [according to the author](http://dianabotsford.com/?p=1502) shall make that even clearer.

And not to forget the Joseph Mallozzi comment earlier in that discussion.

**After learning all this, I think it´s safe to assume that they indeed became a couple, even if it´s still against the Air force regulations, not so sure about that honestly.**

Comment: I find it interesting that you didn't finish the quote from Mallozzi's blog where he said: **Q.** *"is it actually a concensus between the SG-1′s writing staff that ‘Yep, Sam and Jack are together now, but we just won’t make that fact so obvious on screen it’s like a pie shoved in someone’s face’?”* **A.** ***Neither AU nor consensus.  There was never a discussion about it among the writers.***

Comment: Where is the quote from Brad Wright from?

Comment: I don´t quite understand that, probably because of that I didn´t mentioned it. (english is not my native language)So the writers argued if Sam and Jack are together or not? I don´t find the interview where Brad said it, maybe it was at a convention

Comment: I found it:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-Ubm0LqyAQ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they got together. A scene from [SGA: Trio](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Trio) that was cut for time constraints is [available online for viewing](https://youtu.be/_evV0kDWa5E?t=125). Sam says she's seeing a guy who works in Washington.

> **Keller:** *Anyone back home?*
>
> **Carter:** *Um.*
>
> **Keller:** *Though so! Spill it.*
>
> **Carter:** *Well, it's complicated.*
>
> **Keller:** *Show me a relationship that isn't.*
>
> **Carter:** ***He's in Washington***, I'm here.
>
> **Keller:** *Long distance relationship, huh?*
>
> **Carter:** ***He's gonna retire soon***, so who knows.
>
> **Keller:** *Retire, huh? So an older man, eh?*
>
> **Carter:** *He's not that much older.*
>
> **Keller:** *Let's see; older man, Washington. Is he a Senator?* [beat] *Somebody famous?* [beat] *But I know him...*
>
> **Carter:** *Probably not.*

The PTB confirm that she means Jack.

> *"One, y'know, which is more of a franchise big thing, is that Carter basically admits that she's having, she's in a relationship with O'Neill"*

Comment: This is a nice find, you should try and find a clip of the scene and the relevant quotes and [edit] them into your answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I took the liberty of finding the deleted scene and adding the quotes. Unfortunately, it's pretty clear that OP is referred to the same source as the one in the answer above (from 2015)

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the "groundhog day" episode (“Window of Opportunity”) at the end Daniel asks Jack if he ever took advantage of the situation. Jack responds by staring at Carter and smiling, I doubt it was just for that kiss they showed us. They went through probably hundreds of loops and showed clips from a handful. They definitely hooked up in one of the loops far past kissing.

Comment: Whilst some nice evidence for your theory this is still only a hint that they got together rather than anything explicit.